# How to configure Redis cache for Doctrine in Symfony application

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, redis

In my `config_prod.yml` file I have following configuration. Where can I configure Redis driver – options like unix socket (or host), database number, etc. ?

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: redis
        query_cache_driver: redis
        result_cache_driver: redis
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example given by @katona.abel not works, but lead me to this solution:

```yaml
#services.yml
services:
    redis_cache_service:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache
        calls:
            - method: setRedis
              arguments:
                - '@redis'

    redis:
        class: Redis
        public: false
        calls:
            - method: connect
              arguments:
                - '/var/run/redis/redis.sock' # or host/ip with port
            - method: select
              arguments:
                - 13 # change database by index
```

```yaml
#config_prod.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: redis_cache_service
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: redis_cache_service
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: redis_cache_service
```

Comment: Could this set up possibly also allow redis caching to be optional (in case something goes or is wrong with the specific redis server)? So, if redis server is not installed or is unavailable, the symfony goes on cacheless, but without throwing exceptions?

Answer (score 13):

For symfony 4.4/5 here is how it's done, because the docs are a bit confusing.

You need to first set up the cache pool:

```
#config/packages/cache.yaml

framework:
  cache:
    default_redis_provider: 'redis://localhost' # or '%env(resolve:REDIS_URL)%'

    pools:
      custom_cache_pool:
        adapter: cache.adapter.redis
```

And then use this pool for the doctrine result cache like so:

```
#config/packages/doctrine.yaml

doctrine:
  ...
  orm:
    result_cache_driver:
      type: pool
      pool: custom_cache_pool
```

Answer (score 2):

This config should work

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: 
            type: redis
            connection_id: <Redis connection service id>
            host:<Redis host>
            port:<Redis port>
            password:<Redis password>
            timeout:<Redis connection timeout>
            database:<Redis database selection (integer)>
            persistent:<Whether to use persistent connection or not (bool)>
```

parameter info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/reference.html)

UPDATE

if you need the same cache for all cache you could define a service and pass it

```
doctrine_cache:
    aliases:
        redis_cache: my_redis_cache
    providers:
        my_redis_cache:
            type: redis
            connection_id: <Redis connection service id>
            host:<Redis host>
            port:<Redis port>
            password:<Redis password>
            timeout:<Redis connection timeout>
            database:<Redis database selection (integer)>
            persistent:<Whether to use persistent connection or not (bool)>


doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
               ...    
               metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: redis_cache
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: redis_cache
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: redis_cache
```

Comment: I know that directive. I need to find where are configuration for default `redis` type. Code in my example works, but I need to modify it in one place – no under each option.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that author asks about redis, not predis, but I found simplest "out-of-box" way for `3.4.*`, if you just want a quick start:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: predis
                    host: '%app.redis.host%'
                    port: '%app.redis.port%'
                    database: 1
                result_cache_driver:
                    cache_provider: doctrine.orm.default_metadata_cache
                query_cache_driver:
                    cache_provider: doctrine.orm.default_metadata_cache
```

This requires predis client:

```
$ composer require predis/predis
```

What happens now? For doctrine metadata cache we have `Predis\Client` wrapped by built-in `Doctrine\Common\Cache\PredisCache`. Result and query cache drivers configured as aliases for metadata cache driver (aliases to cache provider, actually), so they all use same database, host and port. If you clear metadata cache by `bin/console` or call `flushdb` directly by redis-cli, cache for results and queries also will be erased.

This solution doesn't require any new services.